# Proof that $(a,b) = (c,d)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Show that if the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is defined to be $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ then $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Someone attempted to prove that and started by the forward direction $\Rightarrow$ saying that let us assume that $(a,b) = (c,d)$, then by the definition of ordered pair $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$:

$$\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$$

So, my question is as to why he assumed that $$\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$$ from the definition of the ordered pair $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ given the only thing given was $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$?

Comment: Assume that $(a,b) = (c,d)$. Then $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = (a,b) = (c,d) = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$.

Comment: @azif00. Thanks, but $(c,d) = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$ was not defined in the question, so how you came up with this?

Comment: I think you are confused with the double use of the symbols $a$ and $b$. Perhaps if you write the question like "Show that if $(x,y)$ is defined to be $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, then $(a,b) = (c,d)$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$" then should be clearer.

Comment: @azif00, thank you Mr. azif, but how I should know that this is the implied meaning? The question clearly says that it's the pair $(a,b)$ that is given in the assumption and not $(c,d)$.

Comment: No, semantically, as the  values of $a$ and $b$ are not specified, this definition represents a generic case.

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks, This makes sense! I understands now Mr. Azif answer.

Comment: The $a,b$ are assumed to just be labels.  the definition is "(.,.)" is "(first thing, second thing)" is defined to be {{first thing},{first thing, second thing}}.  That's all there is to it $(a,b) =\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and $(c,d)=\{\{c\},\{\{c,d\}\}$ and $\{Elvis, Tony\ the\ tiger\} = \{\{Elvis\},\{Elvis, Tony\ the\ tiger\}\}$.  that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$ Assume that $a=c$ and $b=d$. Then $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\} = (c,d) \implies (a,b) = (c,d)$

$\Leftarrow$ Assume that $(a,b) = (c,d)$ Then $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = (c,d) \implies c=a, b=d$ by the given definition of an ordered pair.

As @azif00 said in the comment to your question, you might find it easier to define $(x,y)$ as $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$ and using this definition, prove $(a,b) = (c,d) \iff a=b, c=d$